# how to make a specific word touchable for its meaning in a text?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm developing a prose book for iPhone. So I'm storing all of the poems and texts in core data.
An entity named `story` and on attribute named `details` which contains the whole anecdote.

But the problem is here: if the user wants to touch the specific words and poems for their meaning and definition, how should I handle this task? How can I make those poems selectable? 
As like as built in dictionary in iPhone, user touches and hold his finger on a specific word, a popup appears and show the definition of the word!

[a sample of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Snr.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you show them in `UILabel`, if it is, you might interested in these :

[gltaplabeldemo](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/gltaplabeldemo)

[rtlabel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/rtlabel)

[ohattributedlabel](http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ohattributedlabel)

Good luck.